# If any word appears at least 4 times in a list, I want to print it. How do I do this with awk?

Tags: unix, awk, count, grep, uniq

I have a list of species with their scores (1 species a line, 1 score a line), some of those species appear more than once (ie they have more than one score). I want to know which species have at least 4 scores.

In UNIX bash.

```
grep SCORE_INFO reformatted_output | grep -v '\-999' | uniq -c | awk '$4>=4{print}'
```

(grep-ed SCORE_INFO as there are other lines with other info)

Some of the results that print out only print 2 or 3 times, so that's not working?

input example:

```
================================================
INPUT_LINE_NUMBER 0
FULL_LINE 0  Candidatus Blochmannia floridanus
GENUS 0 Blochmannia
BINOMIAL_SPECIES 0 Blochmannia floridanus
EXTRA_INFO 0 
SCORE_INFO 0 Blochmannia floridanus -999
================================================
================================================
INPUT_LINE_NUMBER 1
FULL_LINE 1  Buchnera aphidicola str. Bp (Baizongia pistaciae)
GENUS 1 Buchnera
BINOMIAL_SPECIES 1 Buchnera aphidicola
EXTRA_INFO 1 str.Bp(Baizongiapistaciae)
SCORE_INFO 1 Buchnera aphidicola -999
================================================
================================================
INPUT_LINE_NUMBER 2
FULL_LINE 2  Buchnera aphidicola str. 5A (Acyrthosiphon pisum) SCORE 15.22082
GENUS 2 Buchnera
BINOMIAL_SPECIES 2 Buchnera aphidicola
EXTRA_INFO 2 str.5A(Acyrthosiphonpisum)
SCORE_INFO 2 Buchnera aphidicola 15.220829
```

ouput example (that I'm currently getting):

```
1 SCORE_INFO 124 Wigglesworthia glossinidia 55.224537
1 SCORE_INFO 125 Xenorhabdus bovienii 25.088634
1 SCORE_INFO 128 Yersinia enterocolitica 44.985457
1 SCORE_INFO 129 Yersinia pestis 12.072053
1 SCORE_INFO 131 Yersinia pestis 84.918046
1 SCORE_INFO 133 Yersinia pestis 79.520988
1 SCORE_INFO 139 Yersinia pestis 49.734360
1 SCORE_INFO 142 Yersinia pseudotuberculosis 34.544385
1 SCORE_INFO 143 Yersinia pseudotuberculosis 77.746483
```

Comment: We would need to see some example input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, however I'll attempt to answer your base question:

> I want to know which species have at least 4 scores

From your example-code, we know that:

1. We are interested in lines matching `SCORE_INFO`
2. We do not care if the score is `-999`
3. The species is the string located between the second field and the last field.

So the following awk line will give you a list of names which appear 4 or more times:

```
awk '!/^SCORE_INFO/ { next }
      ($NF == -999) { next }
      { key=""; for(i=3;i<NF;++i) key=(key=="" ? $i : key" "$i) }
      (++a[key] == 4) { print key }' file
```

This would return something like:

```
Yersinia pestis
Buchnera aphidicola
```

If these two names appear 4 or more times